# Neural network with limited number of training data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, training-data

Assume we have thousands of people face images and their corresponding heights.

Data looks something like this:

FACE1 (128x128) => height1
FACE2 (128x128) => height2
...

Assume We do not know if there is any correlation between a person's face and his height.

The question is:
In case we do not know if there is relation between data is it correct to start with limited number of training data or we need as much data as possible.

I mean we do not know if there is any kind of pattern so we can test with limited number of training data and if metrics showed us that a relation exists we can train our network with more data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing cross-validation as like below
load X & Y normally without doing any train/test data splits.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

my_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', SimpleImputer()),
                              ('model', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50,
                                                              random_state=0))
                             ])
scores = -1 * cross_val_score(my_pipeline, X, y,
                              cv=5,
                              scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
print("Average MAE score (across experiments):")
print(scores.mean())
```

And giving the scores.mean() to the board/committee to request more data for further accuracy.